# Azure website Free tier very slow

Tags: azure

The website that I deployed to Azure in Free tier is very slow. What is the reason? Would it be better is I upgrade it to Shared tier?

On Microsoft website I saw Free has "Outbound Data Transfer Up to 165MB per day ", while Shared is unlimited.
Also

```
"Free and Shared (Preview) tiers include 60 minutes and 240 minutes of CPU capacity per day, respectively. The Shared (Preview) Website rates are applied per website instance."
```

are those the reasons?

Is Shared generally faster than Free?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Martial

Azure Websites Free Tier is running under shared CPU and traffic is throttled. With Shared tier  the CPU is still shared , but you have unlimited bandwidth.

The dedicated CPU starts with Basic.  Try with the Shared (Preview) instance and see if satisfies your requirement on performance.

Do also note Shared is in Preview , so you need to be careful if you are deploying any production sites.

Regards
KRishna

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that providing only static pages are suitable for **Shared** tier. If you try to add ASP.NET logic or java, surely use Basic tier or higher. **Basic** tier is good for personal use and **higher tiers** are enough to replace virtual machine and general business usage.